# How do I hide a ad-hoc wifi netwok on linux?

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, wifi-configuration, wpa-supplicant

I'm creating a mesh network with batman-adv and using wpa_supplicant for the ad-hoc network. I do not want this ad-hoc network to be visible to others (on their list of available networks and such).

Yes I know hidden networks are not secure, but that is not the issue here.

Comment: I also am interested in this question, did you ever find a answer?